# Finding data yielded in search results

Tags: data.gov, medical

I am looking to access datasets surrounding Medicaid enrollment, Medicaid buy-in, Medicaid statistics, eligibility criteria, etc.  My searches yield plenty of results, but the actual *data* comes back unavailable.  How do I access the dataset?  The results are: "No file downloads have been provided. The publisher may provide downloads in the future or they may be available from their other links."

What are my options for finding the actual data?

Comment: can you share the url or terms used in one or more of your searches?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to why the data is not included on data.gov, but CMS.gov (the site for the "Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services") has long been a source for Medicare/Medicaid data. Unfortunately, it is sometimes not in the most machine-readable format.

[CMS.gov - Research, Statistics, Data & Systems](https://www.cms.gov/research-statistics-data-and-systems/research-statistics-data-and-systems.html) is probably a good place to start.

The Medicare program has [a spiffy new data site](https://data.medicare.gov/) although it seems to be limited to service provider comparison data, which is not what you asked for (in addition to not being Medicaid)

I see that [data.medicaid.gov](http://data.medicaid.gov) exists, and is powered by Socrata, but it is not open to the public. :-( Also [healthdata.gov](http://www.healthdata.gov/) which may have hidden gems? I found it pretty clumsy to search, and unfortunately, don't have your motivation to root down to the actual dataset...

**Note**: in a private conversation with a friend who works for 18F, I was told that data.gov is specifically meant to be a catalog of existing data, even if it isn't available for download. The fact that it's labeled "public" may mean that there would be little friction if you made a FOIA request, or it may just be an error in handling the metadata, or a lack of nuance in the available values for the "access level" field. He recommends contacting HealthData@hhs.gov to get more information.